# How to assign or return generic T that is constrained by union?

Tags: go, generics, type-switch

In other words, how do I implement type-specific solutions for different types in a union type set?

Given the following code...

```golang
type FieldType interface {
    string | int
}

type Field[T FieldType] struct {
    name         string
    defaultValue T
}

func NewField[T FieldType](name string, defaultValue T) *Field[T] {
    return &Field[T]{
        name:         name,
        defaultValue: defaultValue,
    }
}

func (f *Field[T]) Name() string {
    return f.name
}

func (f *Field[T]) Get() (T, error) {
    value, ok := os.LookupEnv(f.name)
    if !ok {
        return f.defaultValue, nil
    }
    return value, nil
}
```

the compiler shows the error:

```
field.go:37:9: cannot use value (variable of type string) as type T in return statement
```

Is there a way to provide implementations for all possible `FieldType`s?

Like...

```golang
func (f *Field[string]) Get() (string, error) {
    value, ok := os.LookupEnv(f.name)
    if !ok {
        return f.defaultValue, nil
    }
    return value, nil
}

func (f *Field[int]) Get() (int, error) {
    raw, ok := os.LookupEnv(f.name)
    if !ok {
        return f.defaultValue, nil
    }
    value, err := strconv.ParseInt(raw, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return *new(T), err
    }
    return int(value), nil
}
```

Any hint would be welcome.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error occurs because operations that involve a type parameter (including assignments and returns) must be valid for all types in its type set.
In case of `string | int`, there isn't a common operation to initialize their value from a string.

However you still have a couple options:

#### Type-switch on `T`

You use the field with the generic type `T` in a type-switch, and temporarily set the values with concrete types into an `interface{}`/`any`. Then type-assert the interface back to `T` in order to return it. Beware that this assertion is unchecked, so it may panic if for some reason `ret` holds something that isn't in the type set of `T`. Of course you can check it with comma-ok but it's still a run-time assertion:

```
func (f *Field[T]) Get() (T, error) {
    value, ok := os.LookupEnv(f.name)
    if !ok {
        return f.defaultValue, nil
    }
    var ret any
    switch any(f.defaultValue).(type) {
    case string:
        ret = value

    case int:
        // don't actually ignore errors
        i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(value, 10, 64)
        ret = int(i)
    }
    return ret.(T), nil
}
```

#### Type-switch on `*T`

You can further simplify the code above and get rid of the empty interface. In this case you take the address of the `T`-type variable and switch on the pointer types. **This is fully type-checked at compile time**:

```
func (f *Field[T]) Get() (T, error) {
    value, ok := env[f.name]
    if !ok {
        return f.defaultValue, nil
    }

    var ret T
    switch p := any(&ret).(type) {
    case *string:
        *p = value

    case *int:
        i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(value, 10, 64)
        *p = int(i)
    }
    // ret has the zero value if no case matches
    return ret, nil
}
```

Note that in both cases you must convert the `T` value to an `interface{}`/`any` in order to use it in a type switch. You can't type-switch directly on `T`.

Playground with map to simulate `os.LookupEnv`: https://go.dev/play/p/JVBEZwCXRMW

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the type switch works if reflections are used.

```golang
func (f *Field[T]) Get() (T, error) {
    raw, ok := os.LookupEnv(f.name)
    if !ok {
        return f.defaultValue, nil
    }

    v := reflect.ValueOf(new(T))

    switch v.Type().Elem().Kind() {
    case reflect.String:
        v.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(raw))

    case reflect.Int:
        value, err := strconv.ParseInt(raw, 10, 64)
        if err != nil {
            return f.defaultValue, err
        }
        v.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(int(value)))
    }

    return v.Elem().Interface().(T), nil
}
```

But better solutions are very welcome ;-)