# Why can't Go functions return a type with a constrained type parameter?

Tags: go, generics

While working on a problem with trying to enforce valid state transitions at compile time in Go, I've run into the limitation that a function can't return a generic type with a non-concrete type parameter, as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047848/how-to-assign-or-return-generic-t-that-is-constrained-by-union). MRE that fails to build ([Go playground link](https://goplay.tools/snippet/HZr0MI7n7Wm)):

```golang
type MyStruct[T any] struct {
    MyField T
}

func returnConstrainedGeneric[T any]() MyStruct[T] {
    return MyStruct[int]{
        MyField: 1,
    }
}
```

The compiler returns the error `cannot use MyStruct[int]{…} (value of type MyStruct[int]) as MyStruct[T] value in return statement`.

The linked question gives this reasoning:

> The error occurs because operations that involve a type parameter (including assignments and returns) must be valid for all types in its type set.

It outlines a couple of workarounds including type assertions, but I'm curious about *why* this restriction is in place. Naively, in my example, I would expect that's it valid to return a value of type `MyStruct[int]` from `returnConstrainedGeneric()`, because `int` satisfies the type constraint of `any`. I'd expect that a caller of `returnConstrainedGeneric()` wouldn't know that the returned value was of type `MyStruct[int]`, it'd just know that it's a `MyStruct[T]` where `T` meets the `any` constraint. What am I missing in my reasoning? Is this a fundamental issue with how Go implements generics/type constraints, an issue with the current implementation of the Go compiler, or something else?

Comment: "What am I missing in my reasoning?" You're missing that the caller gets to decide what T is, not the Implementation of returnConstrainedGeneric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is invalid because the syntax means that

```
x:=returnConstrainedGeneric[string]()
// x is MyStruct[string]
```

but you are trying to return a `MyStruct[int]`.

The flaw in your reasoning is that you specify the return type of the function when you instantiate it. The function cannot return a type that satisfies the `any` constraint, it returns the type that it is instantiated for. In other words, the `T` the function is instantiated has to be the same `T` in  `MyStruct[T]`.

If you always return `MyStruct[int]`, declare it as such:

```
func returnConstrainedGeneric[T any]() MyStruct[int] {...}
```

or, if the function doesn't use `T` at all:

```
func returnConstrainedGeneric() MyStruct[int] {...}
```