# How to unmarshal generic interface containing protobuf messages?

Tags: go, generics, protocol-buffers

I tried to use generic function to parse different json responses:

```golang
//--snip--
type ReturnTypes interface {
        protoSchemas.Object | protoSchemas.ObjectList
    }
//-- snip --
func processRequest[RT ReturnTypes](client *http.Client, request *http.Request, err error) (*RT, error) {
// --snip--
    case response.StatusCode < http.StatusBadRequest:
        var result RT
        if err = json.Unmarshal(bytes.NewReader(body), &result); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("processing good response: %w", err)
        }
        return &result, nil
// --snip--
}
```

Setup above worked fine, until i added timestamp to protobuf schema and faced next error:

```
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field Object.created_at of type timestamppb.Timestamp
```

So, reading SO I I assumed I need to use protobuf json parser (`jsonpb`), but I fail to implement that, becasue `jsonpb` requires proto.Message interface and I have no idea to do it

```golang
// --snip--
        var result RT
        if err = jsonpb.Unmarshal(bytes.NewReader(body), result.(proto.Message)); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("processing good response: %w", err)
        }
        return &result, nil
// --snip--
```

Compiler won't let me use `result.(proto.Message)` saying:

```
Cannot use type assertion on type parameter value result
```

And also won't let me use just reference &result saying:

```
Cannot use '&result' (type *RT) as the type proto.Message
```

How to resolve that? How to make compiler understand that RT is always `proto.Message`? Or i have to use type switching like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047848/how-to-assign-or-return-generic-t-that-is-constrained-by-unio) which is just killing whole purpose of generic nature of my function?

**UPDATE:**
Currently i solved problem by making function non generic and passing into it parameter `target proto.Message` into which I parse response. But my question above is still relevant to me.

Comment: "Currently i solved problem by making function non generic" — that is the correct solution

Comment: You need to implement the parser for the missing types `timestamppb.Timestampg` and your first approach should work I guess. Reference: https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal